# stringBuffer insert method using capacity as a parameter

Tags: java

```
public class example{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       StringBuffer s1 = new StringBuffer(10);
       s1.insert(0,avaffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv");
       System.out.println(s1);
    }
}
```

the output of this code is coming as `avaffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv`.

what is the use of parameter 10 in the StringBuffer class's method?
if 10 is the size of Buffer and 0 is the offset of insert method then how will we get the whole string as an output?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html – StringBuffer(int capacity)
Constructs a string buffer with no characters in it and the specified initial capacity.

Comment: As a side note StringBuffer is obsolete - you should use StringBuilder instead.

Comment: @assylias: Is it? It is slower, because synchronized, that's all...  "As of release JDK 5, this class has been supplemented with an equivalent class designed for use by a single thread, StringBuilder. The StringBuilder class should generally be used in preference to this one, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it performs no synchronization."

Comment: @Betlista Yes so there is no point in using StringBuffer (apart from very specific situations). In particular as soon as you see `new StringBuffer()` in a method, you know it is unnecessary because it can't be access by more than one thread.

Answer (score 2):

From JavaDoc:

> A string buffer is like a String, but can be modified. At any
>   point in time it contains some particular sequence of characters, but
>   the length and content of the sequence can be changed through certain
>   method calls

10 is just initial capacity (continue reading JavaDoc):

> Every string buffer has a capacity. As long as the length of the character sequence contained in the string buffer does not exceed the capacity, it is not necessary to allocate a new internal buffer array. If the internal buffer overflows, it is automatically made larger.

Answer (score 0):

[Read the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#StringBuffer-int-):

> capacity - the initial capacity.

So it is not the 'size'.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the use of parameter 10 in the StringBuffer class's method? if 10 is the size of Buffer and 0 is the offset of insert method then how will we get the whole string as an output?

The answer is that you can make the initial capacity smaller if you know that it is not likely to be used up. When a string buffer is created, memory has to be allocated. The default size is 16, but if you only want to use it for one character, you can specify that is initial capacity is 1, and since it will only resize when you add more than one character to it, you can avoid wasting memory.

The same applies to the parameters in things like HashSet(n). It will resize if you add elements too it, but if you know exactly how many elements it is going to have you can save a little memory and the operations needed for resizing by specifying its size exactly.

Comment: Thanks. They are usually a power of two, so I had a 50% chance :)